# Using the dimension formula to prove isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $T: V\rightarrow V $. $T$ is a linear transformation. Use the dimension formula to prove that if $T$ is injective, it must also be surjective; if T is surjective, it must also be injective.

Comment: $V$ must be finite-dimensional, otherwise the assertions don't follow.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried using the fact that the kernel/nullspace of V will only contain the zero vector if T is 1-1, but I wasn't sure if the nullspace would have 1 dimension or 0 dimensions. I think the nullspace would be 1-dimensional, because the zero vector is the one and only basis vector of the nullspace.

Comment: Injective means that every vector in V maps to a unique vector in V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Recall that

- $T$ is *injective* if and only if $\dim\ker T=0$
- $T$ is *surjective* if and only if $\dim\DeclareMathOperator{image}{image}\image T=\dim V$

The *Rank-Nullity Theorem* states that the equality
$$
\dim\ker T+\dim\image T=\dim V
$$
always holds. Can you combine the above to prove your result?

Answer (score 1):

We have these equivalences (using $\dim \ker T+\operatorname{rank}T=\dim V$)

$$T\;\text{is injective}\iff\ker T=\{0\}\iff\dim\ker T=0\\\iff\operatorname{rank}T=\dim V\iff T \;\text{is surjective}$$